# Coordinate Bar Units in BC Albers (EPSG:3005) - QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, albers

I am having some confusion with the coordinates bar in QGIS (3.10). Please correct me if I am wrong.

If using BC Albers ([EPSG:3005](https://epsg.io/3005)) coordinate reference system (units are meters), the two values in the coordinate bar describe a distance in meters from a point.

e.g. A coordinate of `1047184,501563` should be (roughly middle) of Vancouver Island

- Where is this being measured from? (Reference point?)
- Which direction are we moving? (East then South?)
- How did you find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All points in every projection are always relative to the {0,0} of the projection.  For an Albers Conic Equal Area projection, this would generally be the intersection of the latitude of the "latitude_of_center" (45N) with the longitude of the "longitude_of_center" (126W), but there is a "false_easting" of 1 million meters applied (false origin values are often applied so that all coordinates in the appropriate mapping space are positive).

Therefore coordinate {1047184,501563} is 47.184 km **east** of 126W, and 501.563km **north** (not south) of 45N (in the units of the projection itself, not true distance).

The `epsg.io` link you provided contained all the information needed to answer this, more specifically, the Well-Known Text description at the bottom:

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / BC Albers",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],  <== Projection name
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",50],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",58.5],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",45],     <== Center Y
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-126],  <== Center X
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1000000],     <== 1000km westward offset
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3005"]]
```

Comment: Thank you @Vince !